# Is npm install machine dependent?

Tags: node.js, npm

What files are fetched during `npm intall <some-package>`?

```
$ npm install tree-sitter-c-sharp
$ for f in $(find ./node_modules/tree-sitter-c-sharp/ -name \*.node); do file $f; done
< omitted path >/tree_sitter_c_sharp_binding.node: Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64
```

- Do these machine-dependent files exist in the npm registry?
- Or were they generated on my machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.node` files, which are binary addons, are typically compiled on your local machine at the time of `npm install`. The source code for these binary addons is what's actually downloaded from the npm repository.

During the installation process, if the package's `package.json` file specifies scripts for `install` or `postinstall`, npm runs these scripts. These scripts often include commands to compile the source code into a binary addon. This binary is machine-specific, which means it's compiled specifically for your machine's architecture.

However, some packages provide pre-compiled binaries for specific platforms to speed up the installation process. If a pre-compiled binary for your platform is available, npm will fetch this binary from the repository instead of compiling the binary locally

So, in summary:

- The `.node` binary files are generally created on your machine at the time of `npm install`.
- The source files that are used to generate these `.node` files are downloaded from the npm repository.
- In some cases, pre-compiled `.node` files may be downloaded from the npm repository if they are available for your specific platform.